# Android Studio Crash (Project not visible)

Tags: android-studio

I was working smoothly on my mac on Android Studio , when suddenly my studio hanged and stopped working. I re-stared my mac, and when studio relaunched I could not see my project anymore. I have tried everything, only solution was to uninstall and then install which is very long process. No time. 
I did it twice though but its happening continously.

Pleas help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to uninstall your Fabric`s plugin and restart Android Studio.